# How to use Microsoft Project SetAutoFilter Enumerated Types like pjAutoFilterLessThan?

Tags: vba, filter, ms-project, enumerated-types

I am in the process of building a form for more quickly filtering through tasks in Microsoft Project. For example, the form populates ListBox controls with field values, which a user can use to select what they want to filter on. Another example is a checkbox for filtering out tasks that are 100% complete.

I've been having to use the custom filter (**pjAutoFilterCustom**) for *Duration* and *"% Complete*" fields, as I've been unsuccessful in using **pjAutoFilterLessThan** and **pjAutoFilterGreaterThan**. The following custom filter works, while the **pjAutoFilterLessThan** filter does not:

```
SetAutoFilter FieldName:="% Complete", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterCustom, Test1:="is less than", Criteria1:="100"
SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Duration", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterLessThan, Criteria1:="100"
```

For the second filter returns the following error:

Run-time error '1101':
The argument is not valid

The entire line of code is highlighted in the Visual Basic editor, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Other non-custom enumerated types that I use, such as *pjAutoFilterIn* work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking a question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_project-mso_winother-mso_2016/ms-project-setautofilter-pjautofilterlessthan/908a6551-b0fa-4982-8f94-bd300c0f15ff?tm=1539725736829), it looks like Project has a problem with SetAutoFilter that has not been resolved, yet. So, the answer appears to be to rely on the custom-filtered auto-filters.